# Truffles? Programming? Are they related?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

OK, here it goes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718403/how-can-i-store-truffles?noredirect=1 (Now migrated to [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/how-can-i-store-truffles))

Is this a programming question? It does have an upvote and an upvoted answer, so there are users who think this is a proper question. However, it also got two off-topic close votes.

After a quick Googling I found that [foodcritic](/questions/tagged/foodcritic) is some sort of package for Ruby — which **is** a programming language — so I guess this can be treated as programming. In such a case, should such questions be tagged with the language's tag as well? ([ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) in this case.)

Comment: OP mentioned kitchen not ruby :) Regarding upvote, most probably that is from a robo-reviewer. Answer is a sarcastic one, I guess.

Comment: [Found it.](http://acrmp.github.com/foodcritic)  The question doesn't seem to match the cadence of what Foodcritic actually is though.

Comment: Oh well, with the enormous variety of programming languages and techniques these days I can never tell! Thanks @Makoto. :)

Comment: A new bot in training http://superuser.com/questions/514970/is-there-a-difference-between-white-truffle-and-alba-truffle ?

Comment: @Iain good catch! Wonder what's the point.. this isn't spam just useless nonsense. Deleted the question from Stack Overflow now.

Comment: Ahahah --------

Comment: Fiends that truffle with us in a double sense.

Comment: We could have migrated this to [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Eh. Should've been tagged chef. Seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've migrated that over to [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/28926/7249) (deleting the technical answer before it was migrated).

Namely, I wanted to be able to say that I've migrated a question from SO to Seasoned Advice, as we don't get a chance to do that around here.

Fortunately, it *is* on topic for that site, as per [their FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#questions):

> If you have a question about (emphasis mine):
>
> - Cooking & food preparation methods
> - Kitchen equipment
> - **Food handling and storage**

Regardless of the fact that it could be spam, there's no reason we can't make lemonade out of lemons here (pun intended).

Comment: I think it's just spam.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ So it'll really show them if we turn it into a useful repository of information on Truffles that is helpful to future googlers.

Comment: @Servy That's the reasoning, and it's already [got an answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/28927/7249).

Comment: Thanks! I am really curious to see if this is bot or not!

Answer (score 4):

If it is a programming question, it has been written in a way that makes it seems a joke.
It rather seems a question for *Seasoned Advice* that has been written in the wrong site.

Comment: Hope you are right, posted comment to the poor OP.

Comment: Same question exactly was also posted on other places around the internet (including in other site on Stack Exchange as mentioned in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157678/truffles-programming-are-they-related#comment455455_157678)) so this leads me to believe it's a bot, maybe preparing the ground for spam attack. Does not look like innocent mistake.